# Qt Creator Tesseract linker errors when compiling for iOS

Tags: c++, ios, qt, linker-errors, tesseract

I'm getting linker errors below when I try to build my iOS app. Setting C++ Standard Library to "libstdc++" probably fixes it but I am not sure how to do it in QT creator.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "tesseract::TessBaseAPI::End()", referenced from:
      Ocr::~Ocr() in ocr.o
  "tesseract::TessBaseAPI::SetImage(Pix const*)", referenced from:
      Ocr::recognize(char const*) in ocr.o
  "tesseract::TessBaseAPI::GetUTF8Text()", referenced from:
      Ocr::recognize(char const*) in ocr.o
  "_pixRead", referenced from:
      Ocr::recognize(char const*) in ocr.o
  "_pixDestroy", referenced from:
      Ocr::recognize(char const*) in ocr.o
  "tesseract::TessBaseAPI::TessBaseAPI()", referenced from:
      Ocr::Ocr(char const*) in ocr.o
  "tesseract::TessBaseAPI::Init(char const*, char const*, tesseract::OcrEngineMode, char**, int, GenericVector<STRING> const*, GenericVector<STRING> const*, bool)", referenced from:
      Ocr::Ocr(char const*) in ocr.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Related part of the .pro file

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS = -stdlib=libstdc++

macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/TesseractOCR/lib/ -llept

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/TesseractOCR/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/TesseractOCR/include

macx: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/TesseractOCR/lib/liblept.a

macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/TesseractOCR/lib/ -ltesseract_all

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/TesseractOCR/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/TesseractOCR/include

macx: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/TesseractOCR/lib/libtesseract_all.a
```

Comment: I'm also getting this error. Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace macx with ios when building for ios.

I am also assuming that you have not cross compiled tesseract for ios.  [Here is an article that describes that process, which also contains a link specifically for tesseract and its dependencies.](https://tinsuke.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-compile-and-use-tesseract-3-01-on-ios-sdk-5/)